# Check if Vim has more than one window open

Tags: unix, vim, tmux

I'd like to overload my tmux binding which cycles through panes to also cycle through Vim windows if the current pane happens to be running Vim.

I can detect the presence of Vim by checking the pane title, but this is not robust because vim could have been resumed via `fg` and this will fail. that's fine, I can just avoid suspending vim (I am after all in tmux).

Okay, but now Tmux must know whether current pane running Vim has a single window open (in which case switch panes) or if current pane running Vim has more than one window open.

I'm positive that this can be done. The solution can be anything from straightforward to difficult and fragile.

How can I query Vim about

- how many windows are open, and
- which window index is currently focused?

Comment: When will this tmux+vim madness stop?

Comment: You may want to look at the following gists before you roll your own: https://gist.github.com/mislav/5189704 and https://gist.github.com/tarruda/5158535

Comment: Thanks @PeterRincker looks like someone has considered this already

Comment: Awesome, so the way they got this working was to have vim call `tmux` back when there are no more vim windows in the specified direction. This is crazy because the command to switch windows originally comes from tmux to begin with! I didnt know vim could do that. It obsoletes my "does vim have more than 1 window open" question.

Comment: @romainl why should it stop? I think it should keep going. :)

Comment: Your question is a pretty good illustration of why this madness should stop: you stack up and nest programs with overlapping but slightly different features and conflicting shortcuts and you end up building convoluted hacks to reach a frivolous and illusory *feeling* of integration. tmux is great and dependable until you want to make it the center of your workflow. Frankly, using Vim in a terminal is so simple… why do people need to over complicate things? If you *need* an IDE, *get* an IDE.

Comment: @romainl can you SSH into your IDE? that's really all there is to it. it's about the *power* and *flexibility* of it all. Once I get done with this (this endless configuring of vim and tmux into an all encompassing environment) I can toss my client machine in the lake and DGAF. All of a sudden my environment is not whatever I can fit on my desk or on my lap, but can be served directly out of beefy servers somewhere. It's probably a similar in motivation to those web browser IDE projects out there.

Comment: I have no IDEa if it's possible to SSH into an IDE. What I know, though, is that I'd never trust network availability or any third party host enough to follow you and toss my workstation in a lake. By the way, how can you use ssh+tmux+vim if your client machine is in the lake? In a cyber-café?

Comment: Hmm, and another thing I don't get: browser-based IDEs. I'm not old enough to be that grumpy, goddamnit!

Comment: @romainl Nothing says speed like a JavaScript based editor.

Comment: Well i already have 3 computers that I *regularly* switch between. They run different OS's. It's a challenge to synchronize settings effectively across the systems. I'll also mention that my question is about efficient keyboard based shortcuts for changing focus. GUI based IDEs **don't even provide these features** because they just don't care. I can already use my mouse to focus vim windows and tmux panes out of the box anyway. Browser-based IDEs are a great concept but in practice they are slow and very fragile, and therefore not reliable. A TTY, however, is pretty damn solid.

Comment: That said I'll still mostly be using Sublime Text when on my macbook. There are actually more powerful plugins available for Vim, though Sublime also has a great plugin ecosystem as well. The run-of-the-mill IDE's i've used simply aren't configurable enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The perfect solution is here.

https://gist.github.com/mislav/5189704